# Transform ajax to json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to transform my ajax code with json, because I would like to do with this way.
Can anyone help me with this, because i dont know how to do it properly? Specifically i want my php code to return the `site_id` (is a number) to my javascript function in order to manipulate it later..

Here is my javascript code:

```
function load3() {
    var flag1 = true;
    do {
        var selection = window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!");
        if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(selection)) {
            flag1 = false;
        }
    } while (flag1 != false);
    $("#user_id").val(selection)

    var flag2 = true;
    do {
        var selection2 = window.prompt("Give the Book Id:", "Type a number!");
        if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(selection2)) {
            flag2 = false;
        }
    } while (flag2 != false);
    $("#book_id").val(selection2)

    var flag3 = true;
    do {
        var selection3 = window.prompt("Give the Game Id:", "Type a number!");
        if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(selection3)) {
            flag3 = false;
        }
    } while (flag3 != false);
    $("#game_id").val(selection3)

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/PHP/mine1.php',
        data: $('#LoadGame').serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
            //do something on success?
            $('#outPut').html(html);
            var bingoValue = 4;
            if ($('#outPut').text().indexOf('' + bingoValue) > 0) {
                //alert('bingo!');
                window.location.href = 'https://support.wwf.org.uk/';
                //document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload');
            } else {
                alert('No!');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my php code which i want to make it with json:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "mysql3");
// Check connection
if($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$user_id =$_POST['user_id'];
$book_id =$_POST['book_id'];
$game_id =$_POST['game_id'];
$site_id =$_POST['site_id'];

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $query = "
        SELECT site_id 
        FROM components 
        WHERE user_id='$user_id' 
        AND book_id='$book_id' 
        AND game_id='$game_id' 
        ORDER BY site_id 
        DESC LIMIT 1;
    ";
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $result = array();
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result[] = $row['site_id'];
    }
    echo json_encode($result);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You can store the result into an array (dont echo every iteration) then after getting all results you can just echo json_encode($result)

Comment: @BryanLoresto thank you for your help. So you mean to change this `echo $result;` with this one `echo json_encode($result)`? Have i to do something with javascript code or i will leave it as is?

Comment: Well , on your javascript, check if what you got is correct. Then I'm not sure but maybe to use it as JSON you need to JSON.parse(html) because you haven't set what the expected response is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $query = "
        SELECT 
            site_id 
        FROM components 
        WHERE user_id = $user_id 
        AND book_id = $book_id
        AND game_id = $game_id 
        ORDER BY site_id DESC 
        LIMIT 1;
    ";
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $result = array();
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result[] = $row['site_id'];
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
```

I would recommend to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and to bind this params into query! This way you will avoid potential SQL injection problems.

Comment: Rakic than you sooo much for your help. Indeed, it works like your way. But have i to do something in my javascript code because i see that we maintain ajax technology..Have i to change something in this?

Comment: I'll edit code so it will contain also JS code and solution.

Comment: you are really helpful. I'm trying to do this all day long but i couldn't figure out a solution.

Comment: @Rakic unfortunately it doesn't show me anything ruight now. I pressed F12 and it doesnt say something for errors..

Comment: Sure. That is the only message: `A window.prompt() dialog generated by this page was suppressed because this page is not the active tab of the front window. Please make sure your dialogs are triggered by user interactions to avoid this situation.`

Comment: take a look to my edited php code. Am i doing this right or should i have change something in it?

Comment: Ok, message it self is enough to figure out whats the problem, if I understood well browser complaining about window.prompt auto opening. But you will figure out this message when we get site_id. Try to use console.log to debug and when you see the ajax response you will access it like you're accessing any other object (ex. response.site_id). Sometimes you don't need JSON.parse function so you may try without that function as well.

Comment: Try like mine bellow, just to print out ajax response to see the structure

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Aleksandar. You were really helpful. My php code is right? Have i embedded correctly your advices?

Comment: Yup it is right, just try some time to use PDO instead of mysqli, also try not to concatenate query but to bind params/values. I put link above.

Comment: now it prints some errors that are relatively with the json structure. Do you mean that?
`VM113:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (loadmejsonornodejs.html:41)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: Try without JSON.parse function just do console.log(response);